# Public key 48bytes longer when reading certificate crt file

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric, x509

When I read public key from crt certificate file (RSA sig alg : sha256RSA 2048bits) :

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE_FILE);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Certificate cert = (Certificate) cf.generateCertificates(fis).iterator().next();
        RSAPublicKey pk = (RSAPublicKey) cert.getPublicKey();

        byte[] pkValue = pk.getEncoded()
```

I will get as result (pkValue variable) array with additional 48bytes on the beginning. 
Why is that, Is my inicializatioin of CertificateFactory correct ?

(Current workaround for me is to remove first 48bytes from pkValue array. Then encryption with public key + decryption with private key works fine)

Comment: Please always post example output - at least for follow-up questions. Always include a language tag on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Java stores the public keys in `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structures. These structures are also present in the certificate. They are ASN.1 DER encoded.

RSA public keys consist of multiple (2) components anyway: the modulus and the public exponent. The modulus is already 2048 bits; it determines the key length. The public exponent is *often* set to the value "F4", the fourth number of Fermat, `0x010001`. These need to be separated for a generic implementation to distinguish them.

More information in the [X509 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280) and you can have a look at your byte array returned by `getEncoded` (use hex or base64) [here](http://lapo.it/asn1js/).